# When should I use $=$ and when should I use $\iff$?

Tags: notation

Is there some rule as to when I should use $=$ and when I should use $\iff$? For me, it seems like they are used interchangeably. If so, what is "best practice"?

Comment: I think $\iff$ a relationship between two statements, while $=$ is used with two quantities.

Comment: No doubt, someone will make this as technical as they can, but I would think in terms of logical statements for symbol $\Leftrightarrow$ and some concrete objects/quantities for $=$.

Comment: For example, it holds that $2x=4$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x=2$.

Comment: These symbols are *not* equivalent. $=$ denotes an equality of *objects* (in $x^2+7x+6=0$, $x$ is a real number such that $x^2+7x+6$ is the number zero), while $\Leftrightarrow$ means “the *logical statements* on the left and the right have the same truth value”. $x^2+7x+6$ is not a statement; $x^2+7x+6=0$ is a statement, and $x^2+7x+6=0 \Leftrightarrow x=-6 \text{ or } x=-1$ holds.

Comment: See first comment above: we have *terms* (i.e. names), like $1$ and $1+1$ and we have *formulas* (i.e. sentences). We have to use $=$ with terms: $2=1+1$ and "iff" (and other connectives: and, or, not) with formulas: $lnot (1=0)$.

Comment: Many answers in the comments! $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Never had this many comments so fast :) Thanks all!